# Is it possible to host FAYE on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

If not, why? If so, any issues or thoughts to share?

http://faye.jcoglan.com/ruby.html

Comment: Looks okay in principle - Heroku supports bare rack apps, and uses Thin as its server, so both the key dependencies look like they're met. The other thing that could screw this up is if it tries to store messages on disk - Heroku volumes are read only.

Comment: Sounds like something that will require a try to figure out. One potential issue might be: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/request-timeout.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it is.

You should check this git repos 
https://github.com/ntenisOT/Faye-Heroku-Cedar-RedisToGo

The README file has several link to functional projects using faye hosted at heroku (including their source codes)

One think you should be aware is that besides Faye's new support for WebSockets since version 0.5, it is still not supported on heroku [(not even in the new cedar stack)](http://blog.heroku.com/archives/2011/6/22/the_new_heroku_2_node_js_new_http_routing_capabilities/)

> we've made the difficult decision to hold off on supporting WebSockets, as the protocol is still [in flux](http://cantina.co/2011/01/12/websockets-hits-a-snag/) and [not uniformly supported in modern standards-compliant browsers](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/12/websockets-disabled-in-firefox-4/)

EDIT:

the faye repo has not been updated in 2 years, but now [heroku has support for websockets](https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2013/10/8/websockets-public-beta), so it might be worthy a trial to use the [web sockets standalone library](https://github.com/faye/faye-websocket-ruby)

Answer (score 4):

Heroku has now posted an article about running Faye on Heroku:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-websockets

So the answer is officially "yes" now.

Comment: This is not an example of Faye being able to run on Heroku. It's an example of using Faye's websocket gem, which in this example is being run outside the concept of faye itself (it has faye in the name, but is a standalone websocket implementation)