# Getting Sure you're not looking for /faye ? instead of my application on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, heroku, faye

This seems like it should be a simple problem. I'm trying to host my Rails 3.1 application that uses Faye on Heroku, but I keep getting this:

> Sure you're not looking for /faye ?

I understand this is just the faye server responding to me. But why isn't it launching my application, and rather sending me to this? (I'm following [parts of this application by the way)](https://github.com/ntenisOT/Faye-Example-Application)

Here's my faye.ru

```
require 'faye'

faye_server = Faye::RackAdapter.new(:mount => '/faye', :timeout => 45)
run faye_server
```

I also have a config.ru that's just the default config.ru file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run another Heroku project for faye, https://github.com/ntenisOT/Faye-Heroku-Cedar-RedisToGo

Other question on SO: [Is it possible to host FAYE, on Heroku?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5123136/is-it-possible-to-host-faye-on-heroku)

Well you answered your own question, Heroku is only allowing one server per slug.  You may still run into problems on Heroku with the free redis instance.  It is limited to 5mb.  There is also pubnub instead of pusher, http://www.pubnub.com/price  Pubnub has help documentation.  There is also the option to run your app on EC2 free for a year on a micro instance (slow though)

Another cool but more work option is to use Torquebox (jruby app server).  You would have to find different hosting, but it has inbuilt messaging.

Comment: The SO question has no resolved answers it seems, but I'll try your first suggestion. The github page seems to be poorly documented -- I had no idea they had two separate Heroku apps, one for Faye and one for Rails!

Comment: I'll check out PubNub. I'm assuming you can run it without needing another server instance?

Comment: You'll read about it, it's a service like pusher.  Edited my answer to be more clear.

Comment: The second application for Faye doesn't seem to be working. I set it up just like the application from the github page... Any idea why this might not be working or how I could find the error?

Comment: You'll have to be more specific than that ;-)  Just create another stack overflow question or maybe make an issue on their github page.  I ran faye, but I ran it on a dedicated EC2 micro instance.  It's a rack application with Thin/event machine, so it should work on Heroku.

Comment: Yeah the problem is that I have no idea what could be wrong because when I check the logs, nothing is useful. There are no indications of outgoing requests or anything... Anyways, probably just going to switch to pubnub anyway. I'd rather have something that I know won't crash when I scale.

Comment: Well can you access the faye app on /faye ?  Is it starting with thin or webbrick?  I know thin is required because it is event machine driven.

Comment: Yeah, It's started. I don't see any direct references to event machine in the example they gave though.

Comment: Join me on the chat, http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5676/official-ruby-on-rails-developers-hub

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure this is due to Heroku not allowing me to run the Faye server **at the same time as the Rails server**. I think the only real solution to this is running a [separate web process through Heroku](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ps), which unforunately, costs about $35 a month.

If anyone finds out how to run these two processes without shelling out the $35 dollars a month, please let me know.

Comment: @Amala I looked at pusher but the problem is that my application is basically a collection of chatrooms, so 20 connections (or even 100 for that matter) would be pretty useless to me.

Comment: Can't you run another Heroku project for faye and use that URL in your app?