# Way to send information between two web browser clients?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, websocket

I've done a LOT of research on my following problem, but it all ends up pointing to Websockets which I can't use because my host doesn't allow command line or ssh. I've also tried the postMessage(data, targetDomain) technique, but that's not entirely where I want to go either.

Here's what I want to do:

Execute javascript from one person to the other users that are on that page without reloading it or anything.

Example: A user clicks a button on the page and it sends a javascript code that automatically executes a function on every other listeners page. Kind of like a chat feature you could say, but less dense maybe?

This is my first time exploring this field so I'm a bit confused over the concepts. I've read multiple documentations of programs that offer socket like usage, but not really any luck here. (Like I said, I can't really use sockets because of my host).

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Ajax and long polling is probably the way to go.

Comment: You're going to need *something* on a server to broker the messages. You can't communicate browser-to-browser directly.

Comment: Perhaps you need (like @Pitchinnate say) something like Comet programming (long polling), which is kinda bad practice, or switch to another host so you can use sockets...

Comment: Yeah, I've been trying some things with $.ajax GET and mysql, but I'd hate to keep sending that many sql requests if my site were to grow larger. && Thanks, I'll look into long polling. Seems hard to find a host that allows command line (most shared servers don't) and for it to be in a budget expense.

Comment: @Gosre thats why you should combine ajax with long polling that way there is only a GET when there is new information.

Comment: Thats why it is called long polling.. If you want an open line between client and server, you need sockets..

Comment: `Seems hard to find a host that allows command line (most shared servers don't) and for it to be in a budget expense` I recommand [Amazon EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/)

Comment: The answer to "my cheap webhost sucks, how do I solve things the hard way?" should always be "get better hosting".  Spending days of work to save $20/yr just doesn't make sense.

Comment: @SeanMcSomething No offense or anything, but you're not 18 without a job and a current college education that takes all hours of the day. That's why my budget it rather low. Need money for the necessities.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a hosting platform that doesn't allow WebSockets then you can outsource the realtime communications layer to a [hosted realtime service](http://www.leggetter.co.uk/2012/01/24/hosted-realtime-services-making-the-realtime-web-more-accessible.html) (*I work for [Pusher](http://pusher.com) which is one such service*).

Hosted services tend to have a free tier so depending on what you are trying to achieve that may be enough. If not, then contact them, explain your app and your situation and they may be able to help.

If you want to use a [self hosted solution](http://www.leggetter.co.uk/real-time-web-technologies-guide#self-hosted) then you may need to go with something HTTP-based. But, again, if you are on a small shared hosting platform this may be quite resource intensive and your hosting provide may tell you off.

If updates aren't all that frequent they you could use standard AJAX polling at reasonably long intervals. It sounds like you'd like to avoid this though.

Personally, I'd recommend using a hosted service as what you are trying to achieve is inherently difficult with PHP as it was built with request/response in mind.

Related: [Realtime websocket-like behavior possible on Heroku?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14908212/realtime-websocket-like-behavior-possible-on-heroku)