# Triggering backbone events from Rails in real time

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

I am using RoR, Backbone, and i have a server-side function using sidekiq, so my Redis database updated in real-time. I need to trigger my backbone event when sidekiq do change database attributes. Sidekiq function is located at app/assets/workers directory. So basically i need that from Rails /app/assets/workers/worker.rb i could trigger my Backbone collection at app/assets/javascripts/backbone/models/monster.js.coffee in real-time. When sidekiq updates attributes in database in real-time, for Backbone everything is silent and my collection doesn't change itself in real-time. If i refresh the page, it updates then. 
How to trigger Backbone events from Rails app in real time? Do i need to use another framework or its possible to do that simply in rails?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This functionality is not provided by Rails out of the box so you'll need a custom solution. I would recommend taking a look at [Faye](http://faye.jcoglan.com/ruby.html), a pub/sub messaging system that integrates easily with Rails via the [Faye gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/faye).

To accomplish what you want, you would need to setup the Faye server as per the docs. In the browser, you'd need to create the client as described [here](http://faye.jcoglan.com/browser.html). With the browser client, you can subscribe and listen for messages on the channel. In the backend, when your Sidekiq worker finishes and updates the relevant data, you can publish a message on the Faye channel. Once the message is received in the browser client, you can do whatever you wish with it, including triggering events on the Backbone collection. Hope this helps.

Comment: @mansim, yes they do. Check out the [Sidekiq Wiki](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Deployment) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5123136/is-it-possible-to-host-faye-on-heroku) SO post for more details. Cheers.